# How to derive the second moment of the Chi-Square distribution with the MGF?

Tags: moments, moment-generating-function, chi-squared-distribution

I need to know how to compute the second moment of a Chi-square distribution with the Moment Generating Function. I know that the second moment of the Chi-square distribution is given by $\mu'_2 = r(r+2)$. But when I try to derive it, I don't get this answer.

This is what I get if I try it myself:

Moment Generating Function of the Chi-Square is given by $M_X(t) = (1-2t)^{-r/2}$

First moment $\mu'_1 = M_X'(0)=-2\cdot{-r/2}(1-2t)^{-3r/2} =r(1-2t)^{-3r/2}|_{t=0}=r$

Second Moment $\mu'_2 = M_X''(0) =-3/2r^2\cdot-2(1-2t)^{-5r/2}=3r^2(1-2t)^{-5r/2}|_{t=0}=3r^2$

As you can see the answer of the second moment I derived should not be correct. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

You made a mistake while taking the derivatives.

$$M_X'(t) = \dfrac{d}{dt} (1 - 2t)^{-r/2} = \dfrac{2r}{2} (1-2t)^{-r/2 -1} = r(1-2t)^{-\frac{r+2}{2} }.$$

The same mistake you made in taking the second derivative.

Comment: The *OP* made a mistake...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, it would be more typical to use $\nu$ as the degrees of freedom, and $r$ as the moment number. Then the Chi-squared density function is

$$\begin{cases}
 \frac{2^{-\frac{\nu }{2}} e^{-\frac{x}{2}} x^{\frac{\nu }{2}-1}}{\Gamma \left(\frac{\nu }{2}\right)} & x>0 \\
 0 & \text{True} 
\end{cases}$$

The moment generating function is

$$(1-2 \nu )^{-\frac{\nu }{2}}$$

The $r^{th}$ moment is

$$2^r \left(\frac{\nu }{2}\right)_r$$

where $\left({.}\right)_r$ is the Pochhammer such that first four moments are respectively

$\nu$  ,
$\nu  (\nu +2)$ ,
$\nu  (\nu +2) (\nu +4)$ ,
and $\nu  (\nu +2) (\nu +4) (\nu +6)$.